# How to display normalized MySQL data in a flat HTML table with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display this data in table format, like

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
```

But my table, column-wise, is like

```
userdbelemnts_id     userdbelements_field_name      userdbelements_field_value  

180                  user_first_name                Demo
181                  user_last_name                 Agent
183                  City                           Mumbai
184                  zip                            400000
185                  state                          xyz
189                  phone                          123456
```

How do i flatten the normalized data for display in the above table structure?

Comment: Is the second table a mysql table? is yes, do you want to retrieve the value from the table and display them in the browser? Please be more clear.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '`separating`' it?

Comment: Do you have a `user_id` in that table?  Is the table called `userdbelements`?

Comment: Sorry, yes i am retrieving from the database. yes, table is `userdbelements`. and also column is there called `userdb_id`

Comment: Ok, tweaked my answer... that should work for ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could denormalize the data on output in your query, like this (Grouping on `userdb_id`):

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'user_first_name' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'user_last_name' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS last_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'City' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS city,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'state' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS state,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'zip' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS zip,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'phone' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS phone,
FROM userdbelemnts
GROUP BY userdb_id
```

Then in your php, just loop through the results as you would in a flat table.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['first_name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['last_name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['city']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['state']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['phone']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

**Edit:** given your new table schema per comments below:

```
SELECT
    orodha_en_userdb.*,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'user_first_name' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'user_last_name' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS last_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'City' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS city,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'state' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS state,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'zip' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS zip,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userdbelements_field_name = 'phone' 
        THEN userdbelements_field_value ELSE NULL END) AS phone,
FROM orodha_en_userdbelements
    INNER JOIN orodha_en_userdb
    ON orodha_en_userdbelements.userdb_id = orodha_en_userdb.userdb_id
WHERE orodha_en_userdb.userdb_id = $id
GROUP BY orodha_en_userdb.userdb_id
```

Comment: actually i am getting the data from 2 tables , my query is like this
`$sql="SELECT * FROM orodha_en_userdbelements, orodha_en_userdb WHERE orodha_en_userdbelements.userdb_id = orodha_en_userdb.userdb_id AND userdb_id = '".$q."'";, so for that not getting how to add this`

Comment: sorry sorry, I got it. I made it!! Thanks a lot Steven Moseley

Comment: Updated the query to show how to group it with a join on another table.  In the future, try to post your question with your actual table structure and problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: sure. I will take care of that in my next post. Thank you once again